# Scrape Google search results of specific date range in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to build a system that allows me to pull Google search results of specific date range to my local machine. I tried the following code:

```
import requests, bs4

res =
requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=nepal+OR+नेपाल&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:4/1/2020,cd_max:4/8/2020')
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser') 
linkElements = soup.select('div')

 open('output.html', 'w').write(res.text)
```

It generates the result as shown in image shown in the following image.
[No date range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZYyA.jpg)

It is showing a normal search result for **'nepal OR नेपाल'** but I need the search results for a date range lets say *April 1, 2020 to April 8, 2020* as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNgkQ.jpg)

With some research, I came to know that this can be done by the use of APIs such as ***SerpAPI*** but that will cost me 50$ per month.

Is there any other way I could do this?

Comment: please Syntax highlighting. check: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try out selenium unlike requests it can interact with the page once it’s there and you can execute JavaScript commands to set a date range.